# Cache hits on matrix multiplication

Tags: c, performance, memory

https://youtu.be/o7h_sYMk_oc?t=1963

In this video he is explaining that retrieving data that is far away creates a worse cache lines utilization and then he follows with a line that I don't understand.
"so the processor is going to be bringing in 64 bytes to operate on a particular datum. And then it's ignoring 7 of the 8 floating-point words on that cache line and going to the next one"
What does he mean by that.

Comment: I'm not going to watch a youtube video just to answer a question (and I suspect few people will). If possible provide all the info in the question itself. At a guess I would say that the cache line size is 64 bytes and the example code is accessing 8 bytes at a time with a stride of greater than 64 bytes. So each access will pull in a new cache line and only use a small part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cache is typically based on cache lines. When data is read into the cache, it's done by reading a complete cache line. So if the cache line contians 64 bytes, the processors HW makes sure to read 64 consecutive bytes from memory into the cache. If a floating point double is 8 bytes, a single cache line can hold 8 doubles.

Now if your code uses consecutive doubles the cache access will be:

```
Access double located in Addr    --> Miss, 64 bytes read into the cache (slow)
Access double located in Addr+1  --> Hit (fast)
Access double located in Addr+2  --> Hit (fast)
Access double located in Addr+3  --> Hit (fast)
Access double located in Addr+4  --> Hit (fast)
Access double located in Addr+5  --> Hit (fast)
Access double located in Addr+6  --> Hit (fast)
Access double located in Addr+7  --> Hit (fast)
Access double located in Addr+8  --> Miss, 64 bytes read into the cache (slow)
Access double located in Addr+9  --> Hit (fast)
Access double located in Addr+10 --> Hit (fast)
Access double located in Addr+11 --> Hit (fast)
Access double located in Addr+12 --> Hit (fast)
Access double located in Addr+13 --> Hit (fast)
Access double located in Addr+14 --> Hit (fast)
Access double located in Addr+15 --> Hit (fast)
Access double located in Addr+16 --> Miss, 64 bytes read into the cache (slow)
Access double located in Addr+17 --> Hit (fast)
...
```

So here you have 1 slow read followed by 7 fast reads because your program uses consecutive doubles.

However, if your program always uses doubles that are placed 8 doubles (aka 64 bytes) from each other, your pattern will be:

```
Access double located in Addr    --> Miss, 64 bytes read into the cache (slow)
Access double located in Addr+8  --> Miss, 64 bytes read into the cache (slow)
Access double located in Addr+16 --> Miss, 64 bytes read into the cache (slow)
...
```

Here you will only get slow reads and you won't get any benefit from the cache system.